# PHP - Print out error on specific div

Tags: php, forms

I know this question may sound stupid, but i need your help. My question is i want to print out this "error" message inside form instead printed out outside form. Currently the "error" message printed out on top of .

Code as below:

Process:

```
    if(!$name || !$email || !$comment){

//if not display an error message

echo "<center>All fields are required</center>";
}
else
{

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);

$insert_query = sprintf("INSERT INTO contacts (name, email, comment, date, ip) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, NOW(), %s)",
                        sanitize($name, "text"),
                        sanitize($email, "text"),
                        sanitize($comment, "text"),
                        sanitize($ip, "text"));

$result = mysql_query($insert_query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Form:

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="index.php" method="post">

<fieldset>
               <li><input class="rounded" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input class="rounded" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <textarea class="rounded" name="comment" id="comment" cols="35" rows="6" placeholder="Your Message" required ></textarea>
                </li>
                <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="submitform" />
                <li>
                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="submitform" />
                </li>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Any help would much appreciated!

Comment: i don't see any error message place holder in your html

Comment: Just so you know, the `<center>` tag is deprecated.

Comment: Do you mean where i want to display the error in <form>?

If yes:
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="index.php" method="post">
<p>All fields are required</p>
<fieldset>


Something like that perhaps?

Comment: Noted @HttpNinja :) 

Any idea how to printed that error out in that <form> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code:
**In PHP code:**

```
$nameError = "";
$emailError = "";
$commentError = "";
if(!$name || !$email || !$comment){
if(!$name){
  $nameError = "Name is required";  
}
if(!$email){
  $emailError = "Email is required";
}
if(!$comment) {
  $commentError = "Comment is required";
}

}
else
{

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);

$insert_query = sprintf("INSERT INTO contacts (name, email, comment, date, ip) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, NOW(), %s)",
                        sanitize($name, "text"),
                        sanitize($email, "text"),
                        sanitize($comment, "text"),
                        sanitize($ip, "text"));

$result = mysql_query($insert_query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

And in HTML code:

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="index.php" method="post">

<fieldset>
               <li><input class="rounded" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required />
                </li>
            <span><?php echo ((isset($nameError) && $nameError != '') ? $nameError : ''); ?> </span> //do that with all the error where you want to place
                <li>
                    <input class="rounded" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <textarea class="rounded" name="comment" id="comment" cols="35" rows="6" placeholder="Your Message" required ></textarea>
                </li>
                <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="submitform" />
                <li>
                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="submitform" />
                </li>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Broken Heart, this is much better! :)

Answer (score 3):

In PHP code:

```
if(!$name || !$email || !$comment){
//if not display an error message
    $eror_msg =  "<center>All fields are required</center>";
}
```

And in HTML code:

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" action="index.php" method="post">
<?php if( isset($eror_msg) && $eror_msg != '' ) { echo $eror_msg; } ?>
<fieldset>
----------------------------
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$error_msg = "";  
if(!$name || !$email || !$comment){
    $error_msg = "All fields are required";
}
```

Add the following code where you want to print out your error message:

```
<div id="error_msg">  
    echo $error_msg;
</div>
```